# jqplot: change legend position depending on window width

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I have a code which refresh chart when window change size:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
     plot.replot({ clear: true, resetAxes: false });
});
```

But I would like to move legend down on small screens. Is this possible with jqPlot?

Comment: You should consult the jqPlot docs: http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqplot-core-js.html
See legend location, for example.

Comment: @HamzaKubba I tried to modify it before in above function but without success.

Comment: `plot.replot({ clear: true, resetAxes: false, legend: {location: "s" }});` doesn't work?

Comment: No. I doesn't work. Probably because legend is not rendered again.

Comment: @Garath : I dont think there is any inbuilt stuff to handle your scenario. Maybe you have to create your own logic and call it on window resize.
You can add your function to `$.jqplot.postDrawHooks` so it will be called after every possible redraw of the graph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 $(window).resize(function () {
        if (window.innerWidth < 700) { plotgraph.replot({ resetAxes: true, legend: { placement: 'insideGrid', location: "s", rowSpacing: '2px' } }); }
        else { plotgraph.replot({ resetAxes: true, legend: { placement: 'outsideGrid', location: "ne" } }); }
    });
```